# I keep getting a not connected error when I try to do the Pyro4.proxy(uri) call

Tags: python, pyro

I'm having a problem with Pyro4 where when I try to connect to my python server it never connects.  However as far as I can tell the server is running fine.  I always get the ***'not connected'*** problem.  and when its not connected, I cannot make any python function calls on my object.

Here is what it looks like when I list out what is running in the environment

```
MELO@fence-with-pyro log]pyro4-nsc list
--------START LIST 
Pyro.NameServer --> PYRO:Pyro.NameServer@29.21.14.125:9090
CASA --> PYRO:obj_c74c1737b5894d90b10d64326e70355a@29.21.14.125:36582
--------END LIST 
MELO@fence-with-pyro log]
```

As far as I can tell everything looks good.  I started CASA like this:

This is the CASA (name server) console output -- (its running)

```
Pyro4 config Pyro version: 4.38
Loaded from: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyro4-4.38-py2.6.egg/Pyro4
Python version: CPython 2.6.6 (Linux, posix)
Protocol version: 48
Currently active configuration settings:
AUTOPROXY = True
BROADCAST_ADDRS = <broadcast>, 0.0.0.0
COMMTIMEOUT = 0.0
COMPRESSION = False
DETAILED_TRACEBACK = True
FLAME_ENABLED = False
HOST = 29.21.14.125
JSON_MODULE = json
LOGFILE = /castle/pyro_.log
LOGLEVEL = DEBUG
LOGWIRE = True
MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = 0
METADATA = True
NATHOST = None
NATPORT = 0
NS_BCHOST = None
NS_BCPORT = 9091
NS_HOST = localhost
NS_PORT = 9090
ONEWAY_THREADED = True
PICKLE_PROTOCOL_VERSION = 2
POLLTIMEOUT = 2.0
PREFER_IP_VERSION = 4
REQUIRE_EXPOSE = False
SERIALIZER = json
SERIALIZERS_ACCEPTED = set(['json', 'marshal', 'serpent'])
SERVERTYPE = thread
SOCK_NODELAY = False
SOCK_REUSE = False
THREADING2 = False
THREADPOOL_SIZE = 16
USE_MSG_WAITALL = True
!(casaNameServer) Starting CASA Pyro4 NameServer
Object <__main__.CasaNameServer object at 0x29bfc90>:
    uri = PYRO:obj_c74c1737b5894d90b10d64326e70355a@29.21.14.125:36582
    name = CASA
Pyro daemon running.
```

Note:  I have tried also setting NS_HOST to the ip address instead of localhost but it had no effect on the problem.

Here is a sample of what happens when I Perform the steps manually

```
MELO@fence-with-pyro log]python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Pyro4
>>> x = Pyro4.locateNS(host='29.21.14.125',port=9090)
>>> x
<Pyro4.core.Proxy at 0x25ac510, connected, for PYRO:Pyro.NameServer@29.21.14.125:9090>
>>> uri = x.lookup('CASA')
>>> uri
<Pyro4.core.URI at 0x257d470, PYRO:obj_c74c1737b5894d90b10d64326e70355a@29.21.14.125:36582>
>>> from Pyro4.util import getPyroTraceback
>>> getPyroTraceback()
['None\n']
>>> Pyro4.Proxy(uri)
<Pyro4.core.Proxy at 0x25ac5d0, not connected, for PYRO:obj_c74c1737b5894d90b10d64326e70355a@29.21.14.125:36582>
>>> getPyroTraceback()
['None\n']
```

What is causing this to happen?
Is there way to track down this sort of error?  Like a deeper level of debugging to route out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally got this all working.  Apparently being 'not connected' is normal.   What I found out was the 'not connected' state is something which can be ignored.  Even the warehouse example on the Pyro4 example page if one sticks a print warehouse page  the warehouse is 'not connected'.

Comment: A pyro proxy only gets 'connected' if it is actually used, i.e. after the first remote call you perform.